# From weak to strong divergence

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

If I have proved that $\operatorname{div}(f)=0$ in the weak sense as follows $$\int_{\Omega}{\operatorname{div}(f)\phi }=0 , \forall \phi \in H^1_0(\Omega) $$

And if moreover I proved that $\operatorname{div}(f) \in L^2(\Omega) $

What additional information can I get? Can I obtain that $\operatorname{div}(f)=0 $ in the classical sense?

Comment: What additional information do you have on $f$ ? For example is $f$ differentiable in the classical sense ?

Comment: @Delta-u  yes I have f in H^1(\omega)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f \in H^1$ then $\operatorname{div}(f) \in L^2$. So in $L^2(\Omega)$ you have for all $\phi \in H^1_0(\Omega)$:
$$\langle \operatorname{div}(f),\phi \rangle=0$$
but **$H^1_0(\Omega)$ is a dense subset of $L^2(\Omega)$** so by density for any $\varphi \in L^2(\Omega)$:
$$\langle \operatorname{div}(f),\varphi \rangle=0$$
i.e:
$$\operatorname{div}(f)=0 \text{ in }  L^2(\Omega)$$